# Hibernate JTA with bitronix and without JNDI

Tags: hibernate, jta, bitronix

Is it possible to configure `Hibernate` without `JNDI` and not using `Spring`.

`persistence.xml` requires `jta-data-source` property which takes `JNDI` of the data source.